# str.readline() with colored standard output catch startswith()

Tags: python, string, byte, python-3.6

I need to parse a logfile that prints colored output in this format:

`<0x1b[32sometexthere[0m`

I'm reading the logfile in with:

```
line = logfile.readline()
```

and then I want to get it if it starts with the colored print like this:

```
if line.startswith('\\x1b[32sometext'):
```

but apparently it's not working. How does Python represent the bytes so i can catch them with the startswith() method?

Here is a hexdump of the line i'm trying to catch:

```
0000000 1b 5b 33 32 6d 73 6f 6d 65 74 65 78 74 68 65 72
0000010 65 1b 5b 30 6d                                 
0000015
```

Comment: Why don't you use `line.startswith('<0x1b[32sometext')`?

Comment: Hmm, if the file contains non printable characters, you should provide a hexdump of the first lines...

Comment: What do you mean of "it's not working"? You mean it returns false? BTW hex strings don't need double back slashes, just \x.

Comment: thanks this is the hexdump of one of the lines:0000000 1b 5b 33 32 6d 73 6f 6d 65 74 65 78 74 68 65 72
0000010 65 1b 5b 30 6d                                 
0000015

Comment: yes it just doesn't catches the line. I tried with '<0x1b[32sometext' but no success.